# ajax including /contact/ from site url

Tags: php, ajax, email

hello I am trying to send an email using ajax and PHP but when i am submitting the URL on the site is being included for example

```
url: "static/contact/php/send-email.php",
```

i am trying to post to this url while the url of the site is http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/
i dont want it to include the first contact/
it is submitting to

```
POST /contact/static/contact/php/send-email.php
```

i want it to submit to

```
POST /static/contact/php/send-email.php
```

sorry for my bad English thank you

Comment: Set url as `url: "/static/contact/php/send-email.php"`.

Comment: should i close the question or do u want to write is as an answer

Comment: Close question :)